# How do I plot lines between all points in a vector?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a vector containing some points in 2-D space. I want MATLAB to plot these points with lines drawn from every point to every other point. Basically, I want a graph with all vertices connected. Can you do that with plot and if so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution is to create a set of indices for every combination of points using the function [MESHGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html). You can then plot each line using the function [LINE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/line.html) (which plots one line per column of data it's given):

```
N = 10;                               %# Number of points
x = rand(1,N);                        %# A set of random x values
y = rand(1,N);                        %# A set of random y values
[I,J] = meshgrid(1:N);                %# Create all the combinations of indices
index = [I(:) J(:)].';               %'# Reshape the indices
line(x(index),y(index),'Color','k');  %# Plot the lines
hold on
plot(x,y,'r*');                       %# Plot the points
```

**EDIT:**

You may notice that the above solution will plot a line for *every* connection, meaning that it will plot lines of zero length connecting points to themselves and will plot 2 lines for every connection (i.e. from point A to point B *and* from point B to point A). Here's another solution (using the functions [HANKEL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hankel.html) and [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/find.html)) that won't plot the redundant or unnecessary lines:

```
N = 10;                               %# Number of points
x = rand(1,N);                        %# A set of random x values
y = rand(1,N);                        %# A set of random y values
[r,c,v] = find(hankel(2:N));          %# Create unique combinations of indices
index = [v c].';                     %'# Reshape the indices
line(x(index),y(index),'Color','k');  %# Plot the lines
hold on
plot(x,y,'r*');                       %# Plot the points
```

Both of the above solutions create visually identical plots:

[image]

**A note on timing...**

Out of curiosity, I thought I'd time my [HANKEL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hankel.html) solution and compare it with [Amro's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702140/how-to-plot-lines-between-all-points-in-vector-in-matlab/1702724#1702724) very terse [NCHOOSEK](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/nchoosek.html) solution. For `N = 10`, there was no appreciable difference. However, as I increased `N` to much larger values I began to see the NCHOOSEK solution start to become *very* slow:

- **N = 200**

  ```
  >> tic; [r,c,v] = find(hankel(2:N)); index = [v c].'; toc; %'
  Elapsed time is 0.009747 seconds.

  >> tic; pairs = nchoosek(1:N,2).'; toc; %'
  Elapsed time is 0.063982 seconds.
  ```
- **N = 1000**

  ```
  >> tic; [r,c,v] = find(hankel(2:N)); index = [v c].'; toc; %'
  Elapsed time is 0.175601 seconds.

  >> tic; pairs = nchoosek(1:N,2).'; toc; %'
  Elapsed time is 12.523955 seconds.
  ```

I was kind of surprised, until I looked at the code for NCHOOSEK (by typing `type nchoosek` in the MATLAB command window). Not only is a variable being grown inside a loop instead of being [preallocated](http://blinkdagger.com/matlab/matlab-speed-up-your-code-by-preallocating-the-size-of-arrays-cells-and-structures/) (as Amro pointed out in a comment), but the algorithm used is also *recursive*, meaning that many function calls are made. I also noticed this line at the end of the help text for NCHOOSEK:

> This syntax is only practical for situations where N is less than about 15.

Comment: You could even add the test: `N=1000; pairs=zeros(2,499500); k=0; for i=1:N, for j=i+1:N, k =k+1; pairs(:,k)=[j;i]; end, end` to show the difference with non-vectorized version (HANKEL solution is still faster!)

Answer (score 8):

Building on [gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702140/how-to-plot-lines-between-all-points-in-vector-in-matlab/1702336#1702336)'s example, a simpler more intuitive way of generating all pairs is using the **nchoosek** function:

```
%# random points
N = 10;
x = rand(1,N);
y = rand(1,N);

%# all possible combinations of the elements of [1:N] taken 2 at a time
pairs = nchoosek(1:N, 2)';

%'# plot points and lines
plot(x(pairs), y(pairs), '-bs', 'MarkerFaceColor','g', 'MarkerSize',10)
```

---

[image: screenshot]

Comment: +1: Very nice! I didn't realize NCHOOSEK could be used that way.

Comment: I remembered reading it in this excellent "Introduction to Combinatorics" blog post: http://blinkdagger.com/matlab/matlab-a-introduction-to-combinatorics/

Comment: Out of curiosity, I did some timing of our solutions for larger `N`. I added it to my answer, and I was kind of surprised by the results. Do you notice the same thing?

Comment: You're right. I did some profiling, and it turns out there are variables that are changing size inside a loop (no pre-allocation) [line 113], causing the bottleneck.

Comment: It's weird that they wouldn't preallocate first within NCHOOSEK. Even still, I expected the HANKEL solution to be the slower one since it actually builds a bigger matrix than necessary, then finds the non-zero elements.