# How do I compare elements of one row with every other row in the same matrix 

Tags: matlab, matrix, comparison

I have the matrix:

```
a = [ 1 2 3 4;
      2 4 5 6;
      4 6 8 9]
```

and I want to compare every row with every other two rows one by one. If they share the same key then the result will tell they have a common key.

Comment: Do *all* rows have to share a common key for it to be counted?

Comment: i mean as given in ques row one has 1 2 3 4 and row two has 2 4 5 6,
so common key in both is 2 and 4, and i want to know that how do we get this intersection in same matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution (which is generalizable to larger matrices than the sample in the question):

```
comparisons = nchoosek(1:size(a,1),2);
N = size(comparisons,1);
keys = cell(N,1);
for i = 1:N
  keys{i} = intersect(a(comparisons(i,1),:),a(comparisons(i,2),:));
end
```

The function [NCHOOSEK](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/nchoosek.html) is used to generate all of the *unique* combinations of row comparisons. For the matrix `a` in your question, you will get `comparisons = [1 2; 1 3; 2 3]`, meaning that we will need to compare rows 1 and 2, then 1 and 3, and finally 2 and 3. `keys` is a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html) that stores the results of each comparison. For each comparison, the function [INTERSECT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/intersect.html) is used to find the common values (i.e. keys). For the matrix `a` given in the question, you will get `keys = {[2 4], 4, [4 6]}`.

Comment: one more question if a is 100*20 matrix, what should we do to compare 100 rows with each other row and get intersection of each row with each other?

Comment: @gurwinder: The code above is general enough to handle whatever size `a` may be. If `a` is 100-by-20, you will end up performing 4950 comparisons, so `comparisons` will be a 4950-by-2 matrix and `keys` will be a cell array with 4950 elements (where each cell contains a set of common keys for the respective comparison).

Comment: @Amro: Thanks. I was tempted to use my HANKEL solution again (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702140/how-do-i-plot-lines-between-all-points-in-a-vector-in-matlab/1702336#1702336), but NCHOOSEK is a bit clearer, and I figured the OP would be working with relatively small matrices.

Answer (score 4):

Using [@gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749888/how-do-i-compare-elements-of-one-row-with-every-other-row-in-the-same-matrix-in-m/1750030#1750030)'s idea of getting all combinations with **nchoosek**, I propose yet another two solutions:

- one using **ismember** (as noted by [@loren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748558/how-do-i-compare-each-element-of-a-row-matrix-with-each-element-of-another-row-ma/1749157#1749157))
- the other using **bsxfun** with the *eq* function handle

The only difference is that **intersect** sorts and keeps only the unique common keys.

```
a = randi(30, [100 20]);
%# a = sort(a,2);

comparisons = nchoosek(1:size(a,1),2);
N = size(comparisons,1);
keys1 = cell(N,1);
keys2 = cell(N,1);
keys3 = cell(N,1);

tic
for i=1:N
    keys1{i} = intersect(a(comparisons(i,1),:),a(comparisons(i,2),:));
end
toc

tic
for i=1:N
    query = a(comparisons(i,1),:);
    set = a(comparisons(i,2),:);
    keys2{i} = query( ismember(query, set) );             %# unique(...)
end
toc


tic
for i=1:N
    query = a(comparisons(i,1),:);
    set = a(comparisons(i,2),:)';
    keys3{i} = query( any(bsxfun(@eq, query, set),1) );   %'# unique(...)
end
toc
```

... with the following time comparisons:

```
Elapsed time is 0.713333 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.289812 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.135602 seconds.
```

Note that even by sorting `a` beforehand and adding a call to `unique` inside the loops (commented parts), these two methods are still faster than `intersect`.