# how to assign random energy E to every node and compare two nodes for maximum energy and also find distance between them?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matlab-struct

As **helped by gnovice** I got following code, but now I want to assign energy (randomly) to every nodes  using  `E=floor(rand(1)*10)` and also want to compare for maximum energy and what is distance between them?

```
N=input('no. of nodes : ');         %# Number of nodes
coords = num2cell(rand(N,2))        %# Cell array of random x and y coordinates
nodes=struct('x',coords(:,1),...    %# Assign x coordinates
             'y',coords(:,2));      %# Assign y coordinates
plot([nodes.x],[nodes.y],'r*');     %# Plot all the nodes in red
index = randi(N,[1 2])              %# Pick two nodes at random
hold on;
plot([nodes(index).x],[nodes(index).y],'b*');  %# Plot 2 random nodes in blue
index(1)                                       %# which node is selected first.
index(2)                                       %# which node is selected second.
```

this question is follow up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889522/problem-related-to-stucture-and-non-structure-in-matlab).

Comment: You would help everyone answer your question if you mentioned the question it is a follow-up to instead of just mentioning it is a follow-up. Is it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749888/how-do-i-compare-elements-of-one-row-with-every-other-row-in-the-same-matrix-in-m ?

Comment: i am sorry my friend, from next time i'll take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign a value for "energy" to every node, you can modify the code from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889522/problem-related-to-stucture-and-non-structure-in-matlab/1890672#1890672):

```
N = input('no. of nodes : ');      %# Number of nodes
coords = num2cell(rand(N,2));      %# Cell array of random x and y coordinates
E = num2cell(ceil(10*rand(N,1)));  %# Cell array of random integers from 1 to 10
nodes = struct('x',coords(:,1),...   %# Assign x coordinates
               'y',coords(:,2),...   %# Assign y coordinates
               'energy',E);          %# Assign energy
```

You can find the node with maximum energy using the [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) function:

```
[maxValue,maxIndex] = max([nodes.energy]);
```

and you can find the distance between a pair of nodes in the following way:

```
index = [1 3];  %# Compare nodes 1 and 3
dist = sqrt(diff([nodes(index).x])^2+diff([nodes(index).y])^2);
```